# Generating additional rows in PHP form with alternative id and name

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am looking for a way to add the following row of inputs using a button (and I've found plenty of examples) BUT most of them renames the **name** of html element (e.g. name = 'price1', name = 'price2') but my javascript references the element's **id**, making it erroneous when new rows are added. Some helps are appreciated.

JS Fiddle just to see the rows
https://jsfiddle.net/n4h5uwvk/

the HTML code

```
<form action = "" method = "POST">

<label>Item : </label>

<select id = 'item_name' name = 'item_name' onChange = 'listMatch(this);fieldCheck();' 

>
    <option value = "" disabled = "disabled" selected="selected">Please Select</option>
        <?php
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                echo "<option value = '".$row['PRODUCT_ID']."' data-price ='
                ".$row['UNIT_PRICE']."' >".$row['PRODUCT_NAME']."</option>";    
            }
        ?>
</select>

<label>Price : </label>
<input type = 'text' id = 'item_price' name = 'item_price' value = '' disabled/>

<label>Quantity : </label>
<input type = "number" id = 'quantity' name = 'quantity' max = "150" min = "0" onChange = 'multiplier(value)' disabled/>

<label>Sub-Total : </label>
<input type = "number" id = 'sub-total' name = 'sub-total' disabled value = ''/>
```

and the Javascript

```
<script>
//lists the price according to selected item
function listMatch(product){
    var x = product.options[product.selectedIndex].getAttribute('data-price');
    document.getElementById('item_price').value = x;
}

//un-disable quantity field after item is selected
function fieldCheck(){
    document.getElementById('quantity').removeAttribute('disabled');
}

//var z = quantity*price
function multiplier(value){
    var x = document.getElementById('item_price').value;
    var y = value;
    var z = x*y;
    document.getElementById('sub-total').value = z.toFixed(2);
}

//clone fields on 'add field' button click
```

Updated :

I found a code to clone my forms well, but I encounter another problem. The clone will always duplicate values of the first row, I want to create child rows that have empty values. Any ways around this code?

```
    //global variable for duplication identification
var count = 1;

//clone form for multiple entries
(function() {
    $('#add').click(function() {
        var source = $('form:first'),
            clone = source.clone();

        clone.find(':input').attr('id', function(i, val) {
            return val + count;
        }); 

        clone.insertBefore(this);
        count++;
    });
})();
```

Comment: So, you want to clone the form with elements having a different id or what?

Comment: Yep, I want it cloned with different id, but I also wonder what is the best way to ensure that my javascript points to the correct id after that. Note the getElementById I used in the JS part

Answer (score 0):

As you know `id` has to be unique and adding numbers to the cloned form elements to keep the ids unique seems overdoing it.
Names don't have to be unique though, so you can have different forms with elements with the same name. And they can be accessed easily by their names:

```
<form name="form_1">
    <input name="firstName" type="text" />
    <input name="lasttName" type="text" />
</form>
<form name="form_2">
    <input name="firstName" type="text" />
    <input name="lasttName" type="text" />
</form>
```

You can use the form name to access specific element, to access the input with `name="firstName"` in form_1 and form_2 you can use:

```
var firstName1 = document.form_1.firstName;
var firstName2 = document.form_2.firstName;
```

So it will be easy to distinguish between different forms, although their elements have the same structure and names. You just create a new form with `name="form_X"` and use `innerHTML` to add the cloned elements.

And to clone an element you can use `.cloneNode(true);` (or jQuery's `clone()`).

**EDIT:**

You still seem to think of it that you need to store everything in a variable, here's an example to do it all, and you can see it's much simpler than you think. I give these forms `class="contactForm"` to separate them from other forms there might be. we can clone 10 .contactForm and have 100 other forms in the page as well.

To get number of forms you can use `$('form.contactForm').length`

To empty text inputs inside new form you can use: `newForm.find('input[type=text]').val("");`

[**jsfiddle DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/samuraii/nmeoxwwp/1/)

Comment: That helps but that button allows the user to add any amount of new rows (which means new form, according to your suggestion). Is there a way to dynamically track how many forms are made? It doesn't seem clean to just prepare tens of var firstName1 = document.form_x.firstname; to anticipate user entry

Comment: As I said, it doesn't matter how many forms you have, you access the form by the `form` itself. You're NOT going to store each firstName in a separate variable, you won't need to separate them at all.  Mind you that you can always get the current/clicked form by `this` (or `$(this)` in jQuery). You're not gonna anticipate user entry, you simply get it, I suggest you read the answer again. To know how many forms made, I see you achieved it by having a global variable `count`.